# Error with doctrine command line tool

Tags: database, doctrine, yaml

**Update**
I have now go back to a previous build of doctrine and now the error is:

```
Invalid schema element named "Roles" at path "RoleResource->columns->relations"
```

this is whit the same yaml file (see it below)

---

I have a problem with the doctrine command line tool. When I give the command "build-all-reload", I get te following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'role_id' doesn't exist in table. Failing Query: "CREATE TABLE resource (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(20), INDEX role_id_idx (role_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ENGINE = INNODB". Failing Query: CREATE TABLE resource (id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(20), INDEX role_id_idx (role_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ENGINE = INNODB
```

My yaml file looks like this:

```
detect_relations: true

options:
  type: INNODB
  collate: utf8_general_ci
  charset: utf8

Log:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    priority: tinyint
    priorityName: string(10)
    title: string(250)
    message: text
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
      created:
        type: timestamp
        format: Y-m-d H:i:s
      updated:
        disabled: true

User:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    username: string(50)
    password: string(40)
  actAs:
    Timestampable:
      created:
        type: timestamp
        format: Y-m-d H:i:s
      updated:
        type: timestamp
        format: Y-m-d H:i:s

Role:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name: string(20)
  attributes:
    export: all
    validate: true

RoleResource:
  columns:
    role_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    resource_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    relations:
      Role:
        foreignAlias: RoleResource
      Resource:
        foreignAlias: RoleResource

Resource:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name: string(20)
  relations:
    Roles:
      foreignAlias: Resources
      class: Role
      refClass: RoleResource

Menu:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    label: string(20)

Artical:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    title: string
    content: longtext
    css: longtext
    js: longtext
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.
Can someone please help me?

Comment: It seems to be trying to add an index on a role_id column in the resources table, but the table doesn't contain this column. Are you absolutely sure this is the schema file that your build command is executing?

Comment: I'am sure, but it looks like doctrine caches the file.

Comment: I've had this happen in the past. Try see if you can find a temp folder somewhere and delete all schema fragments inside it. I run XAMPP on Win7 at home and in my case the temp folder was inside the XAMPP folders. You may need to repeat this everytime you build. Seems to affect most recent version(s) of Doctrine 1.2 for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded Doctrine.

And there are to spaces to much in the yaml file add the line:

```
relations:
```

from the component "RoleResource:"

Thank you for all the help Tom,

Ivo Trompert